# HERE Map - Is it possible translate incidents text?

Tags: here-api

I try to get incidents from a route and as shown we are using es-ES language, but the text of the incidents does not arrive translated, is it possible to translate them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the language for your textual information by providing `language` as parameter and you can choose any language from the below list -

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXXapp_code=YYY&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&language=es-es&departure=now&routeAttributes=incidents
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-languages.html#languages